# how to read 2d array with only semicolon in it in java

Tags: java

I have a 2d array something like this

```
 int[][] arr1 = {,};
```

And I am trying to check no. of col and rows it contains.
 
I used below technique to calculate

```
int rws=arr1.length,col=arr1[0].length;
```

but I am getting the error

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

obviously, it throwing this error  but
I am unable to hoe read this 2d array.

Comment: You can't read `arr1[0].length` if `arr1.length==0`, because `arr1[0]` doesn't exist. If it has zero rows, it is not meaningful to ask how many columns it has.

Comment: yes, but how i read this arr1 properly

Comment: @user9348691: Opting for the simplest solution in your case, Use 2 for loops i.e for row and col.

Answer (score 0):

You only have one set of braces, thus you only provide a single dimension for your array. Use two braces for your initialization, and it will work.

```
int[][] arr1 = {{}};
```

Which is short-hand for

```
int[][] arr1 = new int[][] { new int[] {} };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't read `arr1[0].length` if `arr1.length==0`, because `arr1[0]` doesn't exist.

If it has zero rows, it is not meaningful to ask how many columns it has. You might as well just take it as zero.

```
int rows = arr1.length;
int cols = (rows > 0 ? arr1[0].length : 0);
```